# How do you load the css for a Mediawiki tag extension?

Tags: php, css, mediawiki

How do you load the css for an extension?

Using Mediawiki 1.25.2, I copied the [boiler plate extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Developing_extensions) and edited  extension.json to include

```
   "Hooks": {
            "BeforePageDisplay": [
                    "FinancialMathematicsHooks::onBeforePageDisplay"
            ],...
    },
    "ResourceModules": {
                  "ext.FinancialMathematics": {
                          "styles": [
                              "modules/ext.FinancialMathematics.css"
                               ]
                     }
      }
```

and in the hooks file I added

```
    public static function onBeforePageDisplay( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin ) {
            $out->addModuleStyles( 'ext.FinancialMathematics' );
            return true;
    }
```

but the extension doesn't include the css.

The extension is installed [on a wiki here](http://mediawiki-treaties.rhcloud.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and the complete code for the extension is on [github](https://github.com/owen-kellie-smith/financial-maths-mediawiki/tree/master/FinancialMathematics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check, if the module is loaded correctly. The easiest way is by using the browser's console and run the following command:

```
mw.loader.getState("ext.FinancialMathematics");
```

You will get a state, on your page with the given module `error`. So check the output of the load request (using the browser's network tab or use the [direct load.php](http://mediawiki-treaties.rhcloud.com/wiki/load.php?modules=ext.FinancialMathematics&only=styles&skin=vector&*) url). You will get an output with a starting comment which says `Internal Error`. So, please check your error log on the server to see a full error message and a stack trace to debug this error.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I got to the browser's console from the browser menu > Tools > Web developer > Web Console

Comment: And what was the error in the webserver's error log? :)

Comment: exception 'MWException' with message 'ResourceLoaderFileModule::readStyleFile: style file not found: "/home/owen/public_html/wiki/modules/ext.FinancialMathematics.css"' in /home/owen/public_html/wiki/includes/resourceloader/ResourceLoaderFileModule.php:909

Comment: The file was not found because I had it in /home/owen/public_html/wiki/extensions/FinancialMathematics/modules/ext.FinancialMathematics.css

Comment: That's correct, you can add it there and it should work, if you add  `"ResourceFileModulePaths": {
"localBasePath": "",
"remoteExtPath": "FinancialMathematics"
},` in your extension.json

Comment: It works!!!  Thank you so much.  The text is styled as expected, and mw.loader.getState("ext.FinancialMathematics") returns "ready"